# SVG масштабирование (эффект лупы)

Tags: jquery, svg, javascript

Добрый день.

Есть необходимость сделать функционал подобный Zoomy (http://zoomy.me/), только с учетом того, что изображение находится в формате SVG. Не могу понять, с какой стороны к этому подступиться. Если использовать Scale, то еще и координаты меняются... Подскажите, пожалуйста, с какой стороны подступиться...

Answer (score 4):

1. Cделать два блока с svg-фонами.
2. Расположить более маленький (он будет лупой) над другим. Либо при помощи **position**, либо в слоях.
3. [Увеличивать размер фонового изображения](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Scaling_of_SVG_backgrounds) для блока-лупы.
4. Обрезать фон при помощи **background-position** в зависимости от положения курсора.
5. пункты 3, 4 и детали реализации - отдать jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите исходники слайда: [SVG example](http://slides.html5rocks.com/#svg-example-slide). В общем реализация сводится к наложению SVG-трансформаций по клику.